# Preventing com.miui.powerkeeper in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a background application, and it is working like a charm but when I boot my device and call it with broadcast, it is not working because of `com.miui.powerkeeper`.
Here is the error log:

```
E  removePowerSaveWhitelistApps: [com.milink.service, com.miui.msa.global,...]
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot remove system whitelisted app
```

So, how can I achieve this error and block `com.miui.powerkeeper` programmatically in Android?

I tried giving battery optimization permission, but it did not work.